# Windows: Testlink Installation (logs/upload_area problem)

Tags: windows, testlink

Hey, I got a problem with installation of Testlink.

After Launching XAMPP, I got that:

```
Checking if /var/testlink/logs/ directory exists Failed!  
Checking if /var/testlink/upload_area/ directory exists Failed!
```

I`m 100% sure that I got right path because I copied it from my windows. Now my`custom_config.inc.php` looks like that:

```
$g_repositoryPath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\upload_area';                                                                
$tlCfg->log_path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\logs';
```

I was trying copying the same code to `config.inc.php` (via reading testlink installation tutorials) - with no result.
Now my `config.php` has a lot of numbers in it as default.

What's wrong guys? (OS: Win10) I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Make sure "upload_area" is written with underscore, no space between words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Might have below problem in : `config.inc.php`**

1. First of all restart Apache httpd service and try again to install.
2. Change path as per below :

   ```
   $g_repositoryPath = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/testlink/upload_area/'; 
   $tlCfg->log_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/testlink/logs/';
   ```

And restart Apache httpd service and try again.

> Note : Windows copied path is not working as shown. It should be `/` or `\\`. I prefer `/` which is supported in all OS.

Hope above solution would resolve your this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Sagar007 but it still doesn`t run. I changed copy path to _/_ in config.inc.php and nothing

Comment: @000060 Have you restart server?

Comment: Just replace above line. DO not enter duplicate path.

Comment: @Saga007 Now it works! Big thanks for you

Answer (score 1):

It took me very long to go to the root cause, the issue lies at- https daemon does not have access to file in concern due to SELinux policies. So simple chown, chmod would not help(group and user access). For 1.16 I resolved it with re-installing with sudo user, but for upgrade, an issue arises again even with sudo user.

And resolved issue by executing following commands, I hope this helps.
(Note: You might have to mend attributes to run it successfully)

```
$chcon -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t "<path_to_testlink_folder>/gui/templates_c/"

$chcon -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t "/<path_to_testlink_folder>/upload_area/"

$chcon -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t "<path_to_testlink_folder>/logs"

$semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t "<path_to_testlink_folder>(/.*)?"

$restorecon -R -v path_to_testlink_folder
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Mac OS Users** try this in 1.9.19 version:

**Make Sure with your folder name.**

In config.inc.php file:

**$tlCfg->log_path** = TL_ABS_PATH . 'logs' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

**$g_repositoryPath**= TL_ABS_PATH . 'upload_area' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

After this if you got read write permission issue failed.

Goto testlink -> logs / upload_area -> press Command + I -> in Permission **Enable Read Write to Everyone.**